Ctk ComboBox glitching out
As you can see, my text goes over the arrow, how can i fix it?
this is my code:
class ComboBox(ctk.CTkComboBox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(values=["Arduino Full Kit", "Arduino Basics Kit", "Arduino"],
                       #fg_color="#78BCC4",
                       text_color="#002C3E",
                       width=300,
                       height=50,
                       hover=True,
                       dropdown_hover_color='green',
                       variable=ctk.StringVar(value="Product...\n"),
                       state='readonly')



That looks like a bug in CTkComboBox. Maybe contact the author?

It worked for me using Python 3.12.7

It may be the same issue as this question,

The simple fix is to move the options in self.configure(...) back to super().__init__():
class ComboBox(ctk.CTkComboBox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master,
                         values=["Arduino Full Kit", "Arduino Basics Kit", "Arduino"],
                         #fg_color="#78BCC4",
                         text_color="#002C3E",
                         width=300,
                         height=50,
                         hover=True,
                         dropdown_hover_color='green',
                         variable=ctk.StringVar(value="Product...\n"),
                         state='readonly')

Output:

